# How to generate matrix where sum of rows is a permutation of sum of columns?

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix

For a given integer N, I want to generate a matrix of order NxN where sum of rows is some permutation of sum of column.

**For example:**

3
0 2 3
4 0 1
1 3 0

row sums are 5, 5, 4
col sums are 5, 5, 4

both are permutations of each other.

How to generate such matrix for any given N ?

PS: 
I know that diagonal matrix, symmetric matrix would work here and the matrices like this

3
1 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0

but i want to make a bit random matrix.

Comment: Any restriction on the numbers which go into the matrix?

Comment: Not as such. Consider it to be any whole number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with a matrix that fulfills the requirement but without the permutation aspect: so the sum for a particular row should equal the sum of the column with the same index. For example, the zero matrix would do.

Then randomly choose a set of columns. Iterate those columns, and choose the row to be the index of the *previous* column from that list (so the row will start out with the index of the last column in the list). This produces a cycle of elements such that if you increase the values of all of them with an equal constant, the sum-requirement is maintained. This constant can be 1 or any other integer (although 0 would not be very useful).

Repeat this as many times as you wish, until you feel it is scrambled enough. You could for instance decide to repeat this n² times.

Finally, you can shuffle the rows, to increase the randomness: the row sums now correspond with a permutation of the column sums.

Here is Python code:

```
import random

def increment(a):
    i = 1 # the increment that will be applied. Could also be random
    # choose a random list of distinct columns:
    perm = random.sample(range(len(a)), random.randint(1,len(a)-1))
    row = perm[-1]
    # cycle through them and increment the values to keep the balance
    for col in perm:
        a[row][col] += i
        row = col
    return a

### main ###
n = 7
# create square matrix with only zeroes
a = [[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
# repeat the basic mutation that keeps the sum property in tact:
for i in range(n*n): # as many times as you wish
    increment(a)

# shuffle the rows
random.shuffle(a)
```

A run produced this matrix:

```
[[6, 5, 7, 7, 5, 2, 1],
 [6, 1, 7, 6, 2, 5, 1],
 [6, 1, 0, 4, 3, 5, 4],
 [6, 2, 5, 1, 6, 2, 4],
 [1, 3, 4, 2, 8, 3, 6],
 [1, 7, 0, 3, 3, 10, 1],
 [1, 4, 2, 3, 1, 6, 1]]
```

I used this check just before the row shuffle to make sure the sum property was in tact:

```
# test that indeed the sums are OK
def test(a):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if sum(a[i]) != sum([a[j][i] for j in range(len(a))]):
            print('fail at ', i)
```

Comment: This seems bit more random. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

One method to get fairly random looking ones is as follows:

First create a random symmetric matrix. Such a matrix will have its row sums equal its column sums.

Note that if any two rows are swapped then its row sums are permuted but its column sums are left alone. Similarly if any two columns are swapped then its column sums are permuted but its row sums are left alone. Thus -- if you randomly swap random rows and swap random columns a large number of times, the row and column sums will be permutations of each other but the original symmetry will be hidden.

A Python proof of concept:

```
import random

def randSwapRows(matrix):
    i,j = random.sample(list(range(len(matrix))),2)
    matrix[i], matrix[j] = matrix[j], matrix[i]

def randSwapColumns(matrix):
    i,j = random.sample(list(range(len(matrix))),2)
    for row in matrix:
        row[i],row[j] = row[j],row[i]

def randSpecialMatrix(n):
    matrix  = [[0]*n for i in range(n)]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i,n):
            matrix[i][j] = random.randint(0,n-1)
            matrix[j][i] = matrix[i][j]
    #now swap a lot of random rows and columns:
    for i in range(n**2):
        randSwapRows(matrix)
        randSwapColumns(matrix)
    return matrix

#test:
matrix = randSpecialMatrix(5)
for row in matrix: print(row)
print('-'*15)
print('row sums: ' + ', '.join(str(sum(row)) for row in matrix))
print('col sums: ' + ', '.join(str(sum(column)) for column in zip(*matrix)))
```

Typical output:

```
[3, 2, 2, 0, 3]
[3, 1, 0, 2, 3]
[4, 1, 3, 3, 4]
[2, 0, 3, 3, 4]
[0, 0, 2, 1, 1]
---------------
row sums: 10, 9, 15, 12, 4
col sums: 12, 4, 10, 9, 15
```

Note that even though this is random looking it isn't really random in the sense of uniformly chosen from the set of all 5x5 matrices with entries in 0-4 which satisfy the desired property. Without a hit and miss approach of randomly generating matrices until you get such a matrix, I don't see any way to get uniform distribution.

Comment: Yes, i thought of this solution and thats why i changed the example that i had given earlier. This solution hides the original symmetric matrix but i am more interested in knowing if we can generate something like i have given above. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you swap the first two rows of your matrix you get a symmetric matrix.  In any event, if you have a constraint on the solution then you should clearly state that constraint rather than leaving it implicit.

Comment: If you are looking at the example i have added to the question, It can't be converted to symmetric matrix. Also, if you notice i have clearly mentioned an example in PS section saying i know that such matrix are possible solutions but i am really sorry in case it was forbidden to you.